# How to send a Raphael element .toBack()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I use jQuery to send a Raphael element by class back, like sending something back to z-index=0:

Several Raphael elements class="dot20" need all to be sent back

```
j=2
jj = "c"+j*10
$("."+jj).toBack();
```

I get the following  error from the FF Firebug:
$("." + jj).toBack is not a function
[Break On This Error] $("."+jj).toBack();

The above does not work.  Do I need some squiggly brackets?

I'm lost

TIA

Dennis

Comment: What do you expect `toback()` to do? It's not in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: If there is no way to do it via jQuery then is there a way to use JavaScript to select multiple elements in the same class to do the same dynamically?   TIA

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Oh nevermind I just saw the part about z-index.

Comment: I think I understand what you want now. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will see all elements with the class "dot20" to have a z-index of 0:

```
$(".dot20").css({zIndex: 0});
```

Comment: I believe that you have to use quotes around both zIndex and 0 $(".dot20").css({'zIndex': '0'});

Comment: @DennisKean No, you don't need quotes. Quotes around names are optional in Javascript objects, and around the 0 it would change the type from number to string, but it will be cnverted to a string anyways when being assigned.